# Layout does not appear when added programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TableLayout` that I am trying to fill in dynamically with entries, through code. In each `TableRow` I want to display the content in a more sophisticated way, like this:
[image: TableRow representation]
I am trying to put a `LinearLayout` inside the `TableRow`, and in this layout I will nest some other `LinearLayouts` to form the wanted structure. However, on my app it doesn't display anything, so I was wondering if someone could look at my code and say where I'm going wrong with it:

```
        // Main layout, added to the TableRow
        LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        parentLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // Image at the start (left-side) of the row
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_10sec);
        parentLayout.addView(iv);

        // Layout for the two texts, which are on top of each other
        // The layout should be of vertical orientation and be centred
        // (for the sake of testing it, only 1 TextView is used)
        LinearLayout group = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        group.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        group.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        group.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView name = new TextView(getContext());
        name.setText("Example " + i);
        name.setTextSize(20);
        name.setSingleLine(false);
        name.setPadding(10, 15, 0, 0);
        group.addView(name);

        // Tie everything together: table contains row, which contains the layout
        parentLayout.addView(group);
        row.addView(parentLayout);
        table.addView(row);
```

If I remove all layouts altogether and stick with just a `ImageView` & `TextView` inside the `TableRow`, it works fine. Only when I add the `LinearLayouts` does it break and I can't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried using _YourActivityName_.this instead of 'getContext()'

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set `layoutParameter` of `TableRow` as `parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` and `group.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Hope this helps.